# Deep network to learn orientation from image data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN to classify images on the basis of type and orientation on a fashion dataset. (The dataset contains images of 25 categories, with image of each item being taken from 5 different orientations). I have finetuned bvlc-caffenet to perform classification on the basis of type, and am getting pretty good accuracy on a test set.
Could someone suggest a deep network which could learn the orientation only from the data (to classify images only into one of 5 orientations).

I also have to return the top-10 similar images in the dataset given a test sample. What similarity measure should I use (combination of type and orientation) to return the final 10 images. Also, could I learn a better (more compact) representation of the images in the dataset so I could perform the nearest neighbor queries much faster (perhaps euclidean distance in some vector space).

Answer (score 1):

To classify your images into 5 different orientations you can use any classifier provided you have the labels for the five different orientations. If you want to use deep learning you can use a Convolutional Network, which is the go-to choice when it comes to image classification.

To learn a more compact representation of your images you could replace your network's final layer with an embedding layer similar to unsupervised word-to-vec, this way you would have vector representation of your images and could easily return the 10 closest images.